# Number of Records using SOQL query?

Tags: visualforce, soql

How many records might get fetched from Database in single context using two SOQL queries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

At the moment - 50K in total. This might be limited further for example if you'll query large textarea fields and run out of heap size before running out of query rows.

Also if `Integer c = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Account];` returns "N" as result it means you've wasted N rows, not one as you might expect from other SQL languages (COUNT looks like it's returning only 1 row, right?)

Don't hardcode 50000 in your application, use [Limits](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) class. `Limits.getLimitQueryRows()`

Comment: suppose i have 2 SOQL queries in single context then how many records i can fetch from both the queries?

Comment: I thought I've answered? No more than 50000 in total. For example 10000 in first query, 40000 in second one is fine. If you have less data returned - no problem. The moment you'll try to retrieve the row 50001 you'll get an un-catchable governor limit exception and whole transaction will be rolled back. Maybe it will be better to know why are you asking this question to help you better.